# (Html/css) Pop-up image slider by clicking an image in gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, image-gallery

I have a grid image gallery for a collection of projects. By clicking each image, I want it to have a pop-up image slideshow that shows more images that are not in the gallery. So people can see more details about a particular project.

Is it possible to do that with hrml/css/javascript? I'm building it on Tumblr so functions are limited.
Below is the very basic html/css of the grid image gallery. How should I continue from that on?

```css
div.gallery {
  border: 20px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 20px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_1.jpg">
      <img src="iimg_1.jpg" alt="Cat" width="600" height="600">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_2.jpg">
      <img src=""img_2.jpg"" alt="Forest" width="600" height="600">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_3.jpg"">
      <img src="img_3.jpg" alt="Lights" width="600" height="600">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_4.jpg">
      <img src="img_4.jpg" alt="Sea" width="600" height="600">
    </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open new gallery by clicking on a button/link you can write a JavaScript function which will display every element you want in the DOM.

So, on click add new element to HTML from JS and display provided elements.

Comment: thanks! I successfully made a a slideshow as a popup. but when I click 'next', the slideshow do not return to the first image and keep running blank slides...that will be another question...

Comment: @booboobum can you please create a codepen with your code if it is not resolved and provide me a link to that? I will check.